# Mysql find minimum value and according date, starting at a certain row

Tags: mysql

The table xy contains the following fields:

id | date | value

I wish to extract the minimum value for a specific id and the according date starting at row 12:

The code `SELECT MIN(value) FROM (SELECT value FROM tablexy where id=1 LIMIT 11, 1000) as x`

This returns the lowest value, however, what do I need to add to also receive the relevant date for the lowest value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    SELECT value,`date` FROM (SELECT value,`date` FROM tablexy
    where id=1 LIMIT 11, 1000)   as x  order by value limit 1;
```

Comment: Thank you, but this does not refer to the min(value) or am I missing something?

Comment: 'order by value limit 1' serves the same purpose as min(value)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT field from tablexy where value = (select MIN(value) FROM (SELECT value FROM tablexy where id=1 LIMIT 11, 1000))
```

Comment: Thank you, however this does not seem to work... do I have to add an alias to the code i.e x.field from tablexy x...?